# Semantic web and ontologist books?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

Would you recommend books on Semantic web, Protege ontologies, OWL-API?  I like the *Semantic Web for the working ontologist 2nd edition*, and I want to know more in this topic.

**Thank you for your attention!**

Comment: "An Introduction to Ontology Engineering" is one of the best recent textbooks and is freely available here: https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/an-introduction-to-ontology-engineering.

Comment: Thank you so much!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Semantic Web for the working ontologist* which is, I think, the best intro textbook, has just had a new edition released: https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.1145/3382097. I recommend it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that! :)

Comment: Please tag it as an answer!